# Kubernetes - What are kube-system pods and is it safe to delete them?

Tags: kubernetes

I currently have a cluster running on GCloud which I created with 3 nodes. 
This is what I get when I run `kubectl describe nodes`

```
Name:           node1
Capacity:
cpu:        1
memory: 3800808Ki
pods:       40
Non-terminated Pods:        (3 in total)
Namespace           Name                                    CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
─────────           ────                                    ────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
default         my-pod1                                 100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
default         my-pod2                             100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
kube-system         fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-little-people-e39a45a8-node-75fn      100m (10%)  100m (10%)  200Mi (5%)  200Mi (5%)
Allocated resources:
(Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
300m (30%)  100m (10%)  200Mi (5%)  200Mi (5%)

Name:           node2
Capacity:
cpu:        1
memory: 3800808Ki
pods:       40
Non-terminated Pods:        (4 in total)
Namespace           Name                                    CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
─────────           ────                                    ────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
default         my-pod3                             100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
kube-system         fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-little-people-e39a45a8-node-wcle      100m (10%)  100m (10%)  200Mi (5%)  200Mi (5%)
kube-system         heapster-v11-yi2nw                          100m (10%)  100m (10%)  236Mi (6%)  236Mi (6%)
kube-system         kube-ui-v4-5nh36                            100m (10%)  100m (10%)  50Mi (1%)   50Mi (1%)
Allocated resources:
(Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
400m (40%)  300m (30%)  486Mi (13%) 486Mi (13%)

Name:           node3
Capacity:
cpu:        1
memory: 3800808Ki
pods:       40
Non-terminated Pods:        (3 in total)
Namespace           Name                                    CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
─────────           ────                                    ────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
kube-system         fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-little-people-e39a45a8-node-xhdy      100m (10%)  100m (10%)  200Mi (5%)  200Mi (5%)
kube-system         kube-dns-v9-bo86j                           310m (31%)  310m (31%)  170Mi (4%)  170Mi (4%)
kube-system         l7-lb-controller-v0.5.2-ae0t2                       110m (11%)  110m (11%)  70Mi (1%)   120Mi (3%)
Allocated resources:
(Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
520m (52%)  520m (52%)  440Mi (11%) 490Mi (13%)
```

Now, as you can see, I have 3 pods, 2 on node1 and 1 on node2. What I would like to do is to move all pods on node1 and delete the two other nodes. However, there seem to be pods belonging to the `kube-system` namespace and I don't know what effect deleting them might have.

I can tell that the pods named `fluentd-cloud-logging...` or `heapster..` are used for logging and computer resources usage, but I don't really know if I can move the pods `kube-dns-v9-bo86j` and `l7-lb-controller-v0.5.2-ae0t2` to another node without repercussions.

Can anyone help with some insight as to how should I proceed?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to downsize your cluster, you can just delete two of the three nodes and let the system reschedule any pods that were lost when the nodes were removed. If there isn't enough space on the remaining node you may see the pods go permanently pending. Having the kube-system pods pending isn't ideal because each of them performs a "system function" for your cluster (e.g. DNS, monitoring, etc) and without them running your cluster won't be fully functional.

You can also disable some of the system pods if you don't need their functionality using the `gcloud container clusters update` command.

Answer (score 3):

Killing them so that they'll be rescheduled on another node is perfectly fine. They can all be rescheduled other than the fluentd pods, which are bound one to each node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex. I have 2 questions: 1) do you have any links to some sort of documentation which explains what each of these pods are? I would like to try and understand everything before going on and removing them. 2) Also, when I kill a pod, how can I make sure it gets recreated on the node I want it to? Thanks again.

Comment: 1) You can check the [READMEs for separate add-ons](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/dae5ac482861382e18b1e7b2943b1b7f333c6a2a/cluster/addons). 2) You can mark the other two nodes as "unschedulable" before killing the pods, and reset "unschedulable" after all pods are scheduled. For setting a ndoe as unschedulable, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c6e995a824094a96f7d43a25e897283f83a12997/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch.md#examples

Comment: @Yu-JuHong, this is great! Thank you very much, this helped me a lot!

Comment: I created a pod in the system namespace by mistake, and now can not delete it. It just gets recreated. What would be legit way to get rid of from the system namespace?

Comment: For anyone who sees this later, Santanu re-asked the question in his comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263252/how-to-delete-kubernetes-pods-in-the-system-namespace