# How to delete kubernetes pods (and other resources) in the system namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have by mistake added a pod in the system namespace "kube-system". And then I am unable to remove this pod. It also seems to have created a replica set. Every time delete these items, they are recreated.

Can't seem to find a way to delete pods or replica sets belonging to the system namespace "kube-system"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you created the pod using `kubectl run`, then you will need to delete the deployment (which created the replica set, which created the pod). Otherwise, the higher level controllers will continue to ensure that the objects they are responsible for keeping running stay around in the system, even if you try to delete them manually. Try `kubectl get deployment --namespace=kube-system` to see if you have a deployment in the `kube-system` namespace. If so, deleting it should also delete the replica set and the pods that you created.

Comment: Thanks this one worked. It did not recreate the pods again.  
`kubectl delete deployment nginx --namespace=kube-system`

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If a pod is recreated even after `kubectl delete pod-name`, it means that the pod is controlled by a higher level kubernetes objects such as Deployment, Replicaset, Replication controller.

You can use `kubectl describe pods pod-name | grep Controllers` to find which controller your pod belongs to. You need to delete this higher level object to delete the pod.